# Proxy, how to maintain object by reference?

Tags: javascript, proxy

I have an object, let's say under the window scope and want to track mutations.

When wrapping the object I am losing the reference to the target object and only the object assigned to is tracked, being part of the instance. Is there a way I can prevent this. At no point I made the myObj a property of the Test instance.

In example below, the first mutation is not tracked, but the second is.

```
var myObj = {};

function Test(myObj) {
    myObj = this.Wrap(state); 
    this.myObj = myObj; // for issue reproduction purpose
}
Test.prototype = {
    Wrap: function () {
        const handler = {
            get: function(target, prop) {
                return target[prop];
            },
            set: function(target, prop, value) {     
                console.warn("set prop:", prop, " value:", value);
                target[prop] = value;
                return true;
                //return Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
            }
        };
      return new Proxy(state, handler);
    }    
}

var x = new Test(myObj);
myObj.newProperty = 1234; // this is not hitting the setter
x.myObj.newProperty = 4567; // this is hitting the setter
```

Comment: I solved it with a workaround for now by returning the Proxy from the instance, and overwriting the original target with the new Proxy object.

From the specs it looks like I wanted to do something that isn't supported by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can prevent this?

No. Any code with direct access to the target object can do whatever it wants to the target object, without the proxy being involved. The proxy can only handle accesses that actually happen through the proxy. You will need to overwrite the global `myObj` variable with the proxy as well.